# Comparing Django POST data

Tags: python, django, http-post

I'm expecting `POST` data and want to create a custom dictionary to use when creating a form based on what is POSTed.  I seem to be running into problems trying to compare what is in the POST data.  I'm using Django 1.4 with Python 2.7 on Ubuntu 12.04.

Suppose I have a `POST` field called `return_method` that will tell me what type of return method the client expects.  Either they will send the value `post` or `get`.  Now, I want to create the dictionary differently based on which value I get.

```
if (request.POST.get('return_method') == 'get'):
    cust_dict = { 'key1' : value1,
                  'key2' : value2,
                  'key3' : value3,
                }

elif (request.POST.get('return_method') == 'post'):
    cust_dict = { 'key1' : value1,
                  'key2' : value2,
                  'key3' : another_value,
                }
```

This isn't working.  I'm populating the field with `get` and neither dictionary is getting created.

What would you suggest I do instead?

EDIT: It appears my problem was that my changes were not being updated on the Django server.  (had to restart Apache)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I would approach it.

```
custom = {
  "get" : {
    'key1' : value1,
    'key2' : value2,
    'key3' : value3,
  },

  "post" : {
    'key1' : value1,
    'key2' : value2,
    'key3' : another_value,
  },
}

try:
    cust_dict = custom[request.POST.get('return_method').strip()]
except KeyError:
    # .. handle invalid value
```

That said, there's no reason why your version won't work. Have you check the value you're seeing in `request.POST.get('return_method')`? Perhaps there are white-spaces in the values that's foiling your string matching (note the `.strip()` in example code above).

Answer (score 1):

```
 cust_dict = { 'key1' : value1,
               'key2' : value2,
             }


if request.POST.get('return_method') == 'get'): 
  cust_dict['key3'] = value3
elif request.POST.get('return_method') == 'post):
  cust_dict['key3'] = another_value
```

if `key3` is not being added to your `cust_dict` then the value of `return_method` is neither `get` nor `post`